# Getting empty LogCat when sending application logs via email using ACRA on a button click

Tags: android, acra

Sending my application current events logs from eclipse `LogCat` on a button click.

I found that this we can do by defining -

```
String logcatArguments[] = { "-t", "100", "-v", "long","ActivityManager:I" ,"*:D","*:S"};
```

But when I send using ACRA on button click, the `LOGCAT` is coming empty "".

How to do that with ACRA ?

I took help from -

[Sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception).

**My implementation for button click** -

```
view.findViewById(R.id.logdone).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

String logcatArguments[] = { "-t", "100", "-v", "long","ActivityManager:I" ,"*:D","*:S"};
ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getConfig();
config.setMailTo("blabla@xyz.com");

config.setResToastText(R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast);

config.setLogcatArguments(logcatArguments);

try
{
config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST);
}
catch (ACRAConfigurationException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
ACRA.setConfig(config);

ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);

try {
        config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT);
    } catch (ACRAConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

ACRA.setConfig(config);
}
});
```

**My application class code** -

```
  @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
        mailTo = "blabla@xyz.com",
        customReportContent = { ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE, ReportField.USER_COMMENT, ReportField.USER_EMAIL, 
        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.BRAND, ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, 
        ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.STACK_TRACE,  ReportField.APPLICATION_LOG, 
        ReportField.LOGCAT
        },
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
        resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text)


@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to set up ACRA. My issue was that I did not include permission for reading log in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>
```

Just a double checking.